# ICU files needed during run time

Tags: icu

In order to understand ICU and its APIs, I wrote a sample program and the libraries this code would link against are -licuuc and -licui18n. The libraries were available because the libicu-devel.x86_64 package was installed on the test system.

In my quest to understand how to integrate ICU library with my application that is targeted for a centOS platform, I stumbled across this [page](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata), which says:

**For simple use of ICU's predefined data, this section on data management can safely be skipped. The data is built into a library that is loaded along with the rest of ICU. No specific action or setup is required of either the application program or the execution environment.**

This indicates that if the application has no intention of adding its own data, the data available in the libraries can be used. On my test system where ICU is installed, these are the files:

```
$ sudo find . -name "*icu*"
./opt/rbt_boost/include/boost/regex/icu.hpp
./lib64/libicui18n.so.42
./lib64/libicui18n.so.42.1
./lib64/libicuuc.so.42.1
./lib64/libicuuc.so.42
./usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42
./usr/lib64/libicule.so
./usr/lib64/libicuio.so.42
./usr/lib64/libicutu.so
./usr/lib64/libiculx.so.42.1
./usr/lib64/pkgconfig/icu.pc
./usr/lib64/libicui18n.so
./usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.42.1
./usr/lib64/libicule.so.42.1
./usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42.1
./usr/lib64/libiculx.so
./usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.42
./usr/lib64/libicuio.so.42.1
./usr/lib64/icu
./usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42
./usr/lib64/libicule.so.42
./usr/lib64/libicutu.so.42.1
./usr/lib64/libicuio.so
./usr/lib64/libicudata.so
./usr/lib64/libicudata.so.42.1
./usr/lib64/libiculx.so.42
./usr/lib64/libicutu.so.42
./usr/lib64/libicuuc.so
./usr/bin/icu-config
./usr/share/icu
./usr/share/man/man1/icu-config.1.gz
./var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/e59bf24facac0acba1622a5180d0e2a22dda69c8-libicu-devel-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2-x86_64
./var/lib/yum/yumdb/l/7062f72703a5afbf894d617b94db3d4769fe643d-libicu-4.2.1-9.1.el6_2-x86_64
```

Questions:

1. Which of these ICU libraries (and files) should be packaged with the application for ICU data to be available at run time? As mentioned earlier, I used libicui18n and libicuuc libraries for linking, so these need to be present.
2. Aside from the above two libraries, libicudata, going by the name, seems to be the obvious candidate. Correct?
3. Is there a static version of libicui18n and libicuuc libraries available for use or does one have to build it?

In general, what is the process followed for integrating ICU with a product?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. ICU always needs to link against its data library.
2. Here's a [very general](http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-Library-Dependencies-C-) discussion about which libraries you ened.
3. ICU has to be built with the [--enable-static](http://userguide.icu-project.org/packaging#TOC-Link-to-ICU-statically) option to allow static linkage.

Ideally you will want to use [pkg-config](http://userguide.icu-project.org/howtouseicu#TOC-C-Makefiles) to manage your linkage against ICU.

If you are on centOS, rather than linking statically (with its headaches), you might consider just compiling against the [libicu-devel](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libicu-devel) package (using pkg-config as mentioned above) and then at run time your users can just include the appropriate [libicu](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libicu&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=) package.