# GCC ICU 57 static linking

Tags: gcc, static-linking, icu

I am trying to link ICU 57 to my binary file. That does not work even thought (I think at least) I am linking the static lib files.
Here is a blunt example:

```
gcc -static /usr/lib/libicui18n.a /usr/lib/libicuuc.a /usr/lib/libicudata.a /usr/lib/libicule.a /usr/lib/libiculx.a /usr/lib/libicutu.a /usr/lib/libicuuc.a /usr/lib/libicuio.a obj/ex.o obj/msg.o -o bin/ex
```

This is the error message that I get:

```
src/msg.c:5: undefined reference to `u_fopen_57'
src/msg.c:9: undefined reference to `u_fgetfile_57'
src/msg.c:10: undefined reference to `u_fgetfile_57'
src/msg.c:11: undefined reference to `u_frewind_57'
src/msg.c:18: undefined reference to `u_fgetc_57'
src/msg.c:17: undefined reference to `u_feof_57'
src/msg.c:25: undefined reference to `u_fclose_57'
```

Linking the dynamic libs works fine though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, I'd recommend using `pkg-config` as I recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38468693/185799),

specifically with `pkg-config --static …` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586503/how-to-use-pkg-config-to-link-a-library-statically)